# subList() has a different behavior than other similiar Collections methods, once subList is changed

Tags: java, collections

Can anyone explain why *subList()* doesn't behave as *subSet()* method, and throws a **ConcurrentModificationException**, while *subSet* not. Both methods created a Backed Collection, so probably the *subList() method* designers created this method relying on a unmodifiable original list, but wouldn't be better if all Backed Collections had the same behavior (like **subSet()**)?

**// code**

```
public class ConcurrentModificationException {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = {"Java","Python","Pearl","Ada","Javascript","Go","Clojure"};
    subListEx(array);
    subSetEx(array);
}

private static void subListEx(String[] array) {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
    List<String> l2 = l.subList(2, 4);
    System.out.println(l.getClass().getName());

    // l.add("Ruby"); // ConcurrentModificationException
    // l.remove(2); // ConcurrentModificationException
    l2.remove("Ada"); // OK
    for (String s:l) { System.out.print(s+", "); } 
    System.out.println();
    for (String s:l2) { System.out.print(s+", "); }
}

private static void subSetEx(String[] array) {
    SortedSet<String> s1 = new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
    SortedSet<String> s2 = s1.subSet("Java", "Python");
    s1.remove("Ada");

    for (String s:s1) { System.out.print(s+", "); } 
    System.out.println();
    for (String s:s2) { System.out.print(s+", "); }
}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are never *guaranteed* to receive that exception. The real answer is that it depends how and which items are removed from the container implementation as to whether you'll receive it or not.

Comment: Same behavior: subSet() doesn't complains at all, even if I change this line to s1.remove("Pearl"); or s1.remove("Java");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already clear that the behaviour is as per documented. But I think your main question is why is the behaviour different for `ArrayList` and `TreeSet`. Well, it has to do with how data is stored internally in both the collections.

An `ArrayList` internally uses an array to store the data, which is re-sized as the size of `ArrayList` dynamically increases. Now, when you create a `subList` of your given list, original list with the specified indices is associated with the `subList`. So, any structural changes (that screws the indexing of the original array), done in the original list, will make the index stored as a part of sublist meaningless. That is why any structural changes is not allowed in case of `ArrayList#subList` method.
The subList method returns you an instance of an `inner` class named `SubList` inside the `ArrayList` class, which looks like:

```
private class SubList extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess {
    private final AbstractList<E> parent;
    private final int parentOffset;
    private final int offset;
    int size;

    SubList(AbstractList<E> parent,
            int offset, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.parentOffset = fromIndex;
        this.offset = offset + fromIndex;
        this.size = toIndex - fromIndex;
        this.modCount = ArrayList.this.modCount;
    }
```

As you see, the `SubList` contains a reference to the original list. And the `parentOffset` is nothing but the starting index of the `subList` you are creating. Now modifying the original `list` will possibly change the value at `fromIndex` in original list, but not inside the `SubList`. In that case, `parentOffset` in `SubList` class and `fromIndex` in original list, will point to different array elements. It might also be possible that at some point the original array becomes shorter enough to invalidate index stored in the `SubList` and make it `OutOfRange`. This is certainly not desirable, and the semantics of the subList returned is considered *undefined*, on such structural changes to original list.

On the other hand, a `TreeSet` stores it's data internally in a `TreeMap`. Now as there is no such concept of indices in a `Map`, there is no issue of indices breaking up. A `Map` is nothing but a mapping of *key-value* pair. Creating a *SubSet* involves creating a *SubMap* which is backed by the original `Map`. Modifying the original `Set` will just require the corresponding *key-value* mapping being invalidated, thus propagating the changes to the `subMap` created for the `subSet`.

Comment: @CésarBarbosa. Haha :) Trust me. I'm not. Anyways, you're welcome :)

Comment: @RohitJain  This is based on implementation, but also perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

The contract for [`List.subList(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) covers this. Here are the relevant parts, emphasis mine.

> The returned list is backed by this list, so **non-structural changes** in
>   the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.
>   ...
>   The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the
>   backing list (i.e., this list) is **structurally modified** in any way
>   other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those
>   that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a
>   fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

In your sample, you are making structural changes to the backing list, thus the results are undefined.

Comment: Right, I got the way it is. But why so? Wouldn't be better if all backed collections had the same permissive behavior like subSet? It wouldn't be more intuitive?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is very clear:  `aList.subList()` returns a view of the list.  The returned object **is** backed by the original list, or so you should assume.

The documentation is also very clear regarding `Set`s:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast: if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

Why producing the issue with `List`s is easier than with `Set`'s?  Because when in a `Set` you delete an element the effect is very clear:  the element is not in the set anymore, both for the set and any subset.  Same thing with insert operations.  But when you delete an element from a `List`, does it mean that sublists adjust their indices accordingly (and possibly size), or they just preserve their size by adding elements from the right or the left?  And, in the second case, what if the backing list becomes too short?  The behavior is too complex to define.  And also too limiting for implementations.

Example:  A list is [a,b,c,d], a sublist is list.subList(1,3) ([b,c]).  `a` is removed from list.  The effect in list is clear.  But does sublist stays [b,c] (changing its range to (0,2)), or becomes [c,d] (preserving its range in (1,3))?

Example:  A list is [a,b,c,d], a sublist is list.subList(1,3) ([b,c]).  `b` is removed from list.  Again, the effect in list is clear.  But does sublist become [c] (1,2), [a,c] (0,2), or [c,d] (1,3)?

Comment: subSet is also backed on its original set

Comment: That only means that you need to try harder to produce the same issue with `Set`s.  And even if you are never able to reproduce it, you should still not count on it.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for both are very clear on this:

From [ArrayList.sublist()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

So while you're not guaranteed to receive a `ConcurrentModificationException`, it's not out of the question. The behavior is undefined if you modify the backing list.

Whereas...

From [TreeSet.subSet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#subSet%28E,%20E%29)

> Returns a view of the portion of this set whose elements range from fromElement, inclusive, to toElement, exclusive. (If fromElement and toElement are equal, the returned set is empty.) The returned set is backed by this set, so changes in the returned set are reflected in this set, and vice-versa. The returned set supports all optional set operations that this set supports.

There is no cautioning here and modifications to the backing set are fine and pose no issue.

Comment: Right, I got it. But why so? Wouldn't be better if all backed collections had the same permissive behavior like subSet? It wouldn't be more intuitive?

Comment: Sure, and it'd be great if I had a flying car too :) The issue is that depending on the data structure it may simply not be (feasibly) possible.

Comment: I imagine that if the designers of the language could, they would provide to us even a flying car :), but what I wanted to understand was why they acted this way, 'cause the behavior of subset() is more intuitive.